# Permutation programming challenge (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Ok, so I have a programming challenge which I have tried solving myself but am really struggling with.
To start off you have an Array of Strings (called 'words'), each of these Strings is a single word.

```
search_query = "these are all the words I start off with";        
String[] queries = search_query.split(" ");
```

The challenge is to output another array where each item in the array is one or more words long and the array contains every permutation of the words, but keeps the words in the original order, as well being consecutive.
For example, the array for this string:

```
"one two three"
```

Should be:

```
{"one", "one two", "one two three", "two", "two three", "three"}
```

The order these items end up in is not important, however I am going to be going through this algorithm quite often so efficiency is somewhat important.

### (Spoilers if you want to try it entirely yourself...)

Here is all my code I have so far:

```
search_query = "these are all the words I start off with";        
String[] queries = search_query.split(" ");
ArrayList<String> final_list = new ArrayList<>();
String query;

for (int i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {     //i is the start index for one segment which will become a single item
    for (int j = i; j < queries.length; j++) { //j is the end index for one segment which will become a single item
        query = "";
        for (int k = i; k < j; k++) {  
   //each item in final_list is made up from the items in queries from index i to k, 
   // where k <=j and k >=i
            query += queries[k] + " ";
            final_list.add(query);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: These are not permutations, but something like subsets. Furthermore, your example lacks the case "one, three".

Comment: "These are not permutations, but something like subsets" I know permutations wasn't the best word, but I wasn't sure what else to use.  "your example lacks the case "one, three".": Sorry, I made an edit, I intended the sections to be in consecutive order in addition to the other parameters.

Comment: If n is the number of words, then every binary number with n bits represents a solution where 1 means include the word and 0 means skip the word: 1=001=three, 2=010=two, 3=011=two+three, 4=100=one, 5=101=one+three, 6=110=one+two, 7=111=one+two+three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution of your problem,
you have a problem in your 3ed loop, you don't need it!

You just need to loop through your *`start(i)`* and *`end(j)`* indices as shown below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String search_query = "one two three";
    String[] queries = search_query.split(" ");

    List<String> liste = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
        String query  = "";
        for (int j = i; j < queries.length; j++) {
            query  += queries[j] + " ";
            liste.add(query);
        }
    }

    for (String y : liste) {
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I am quite a novice programmer; would anything change by splitting the declaration/assignment of 'query'? so that it is declared outside the for loop and then reassigned to "" inside of the for loop?

Comment: you are welcom, i really don't understand what is your question here: **would anything change by splitting the declaration/assignment of 'query'? so that it is declared outside the for loop and then reassigned to "" inside of the for loop?**

Comment: My understanding is that by putting a declaration inside the for loop, Java is redeclaring the 'query' variable each time. Would it be better practice to declare it outside the for loop and then assign it to an empty string inside the for loop, thereby possible saving time/memory/something? (because it does not have to unnecessarily declare a new variable each time)

Comment: @Beyarkay yes this is true, you can declare your variable outside the loop and then assign it to an empty string inside the for loop, yes this is better.